# (Un)equals method for Strings

Tags: java, string, equals

I want to compare 2 strings and see if they are different. Like this:

```
Boolean diag = true;
diag && (tableStr[0][0] != " ");
```

Is there something like `str1.equals(str2)` for comparing different strings?

Comment: Are you looking for `!`?

Comment: How you negate a boolean expression in Java?

Comment: Just invert the comparison.. `!str1.equals(str2)`

Comment: To be clear, before this question disappears, _all_ Java `Object`s possess an `equals` method, and therefore `String` does as well. Whether or not it is implemented appropriately is a different story though (for `String` it is implemented correctly!).

Comment: I used !str1.equals(str2) but my teacher pointed that there was a better way than this. However I didn't find anything better, so I was wondering if there was a method like equals.

Comment: Are you sure your teacher was talking about `!str.equals(str2)`? Maybe (s)he was referring to `true && anything` form where `true` is redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!= checks for Object references whereas equals method checks for meaningfully equal Objects.So I suggest you use equals

Your code becomes

```
Boolean diag = true;
diag && (!" ".equals(tableStr[0][0])){
//TODO code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the negation operator `!`

```
Boolean diag = true;
diag && (!" ".equals(tableStr[0][0]));
```

Comment: Maybe it is better to use " ".equals(tableStr[0][0]). Do need to check for null.

Comment: This will throw null pointer exception if tableStr[0][0] is null

Comment: @VasilLukach sometimes it is good to throw NPE. It helps track bugs in code.

Comment: @VasilLukach Yeah I agree.. I've edited the answer to reflect this.